# Inserting decoded JSON string into MYSQL where JSON string variable length

Tags: php, mysql, json

I can decode and insert JSON strings into mysql. Thats fine where the JSON data does not vary in length

I am currently trying to insert train timetable JSON strings into mysql

So for each journey I get a single JSON string (I am decoding them individually as thousands of them)

Each JSON string gives a Unique Identifier for the train , some operating characteristics, etc but more importantly the locations it visits and timings at those locations.

My problem is that there may be one location or 100 locations - it varies every time

The below code shows me decoding and echo'ing the tiploc code (ie locaton).

How do I insert into mysql a varying amount of locatons...........ie location 1 , location 2 , location 3 etc....................against one single UID. I have put ?????next to that bit of code below. Also don't know how I tell my database to expect 1 to 100 locations?

Thanks

```
if (($data->JsonScheduleV1->CIF_stp_indicator)<>"C") {

    $uid=($data->JsonScheduleV1->CIF_train_uid);

    echo "NEW LINE OF JSON";

    foreach ($data->JsonScheduleV1->schedule_segment->schedule_location 
             as $route) {
        $tiploc=$route->tiploc_code;
        echo $tiploc;
        ?????mysqli_query($mysql_link,"INSERT INTO teststp (uid,tiploc)
        VALUES ('$uid','$tiploc')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a quick google on `mysql one to many` and you will find out how it should be done.

Comment: to be honest, it sounds like a object-store data model might be better, i.e. like MongoDB, as you can store an object of anysize against an identifier under no uniform field structure.

Comment: Thanks Riggs - will investigate

Comment: As long as the uid is NOT the primary key for the table, this should work fine.  It's just a simple lookup table based on the uid.  "SELECT * from teststp where uid = ##" will return all rows for that ##.  If there's additional info associated with the uid, it should be in a separate table, where the uid could, potentially, be the primary key.